# How to custom legend highchart map visualization like this

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I need to make the legend like this but not sure how to custom the text, and type of legend into dots

[image]

But this is my current result

[image]

Current configuration:

```
colors: ["#B7B7B7", "#861086"],
legend: {
  enabled: true,
  title: {
     text: "Legend",
  },
  align: "left",
  verticalAlign: "bottom",
  floating: true,
  layout: "vertical",
  valueDecimals: 0,
  symbolRadius: 0,
  symbolHeight: 50,
},
  series: [
    {
      data: [],
      joinBy: ["iso-a3", "key"],
      name: "Random data",
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
  ],
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to do this by creating an additional empty series that will be located under the current one, then you will have two elements in the legend that can be adjusted accordingly.

```js
legend: {
  title: {
    text: 'Legend',
  },
  align: 'left',
  verticalAlign: 'bottom',
  layout: 'vertical',
  floating: true,
  reversed: true
},
series: [{
  name: 'NOT ADOPTED',
  color: 'gray'
}, {
  name: 'ADOPTED',
  color: 'purple',
  data: [{
    'hc-key': 'br',
  }, {
    'hc-key': 'us',
  }, {
    'hc-key': 'in',
  }],
  keys: ['hc-key', ],
}]
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ujzwsn54/